# Can the Linux kernel shuffle Ethernet frames?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I have an FPGA connected to a Linux x86 via an Arista switch. The FPGA-to-Arista link is 10Gb Ethernet, and the Arista-to-x86 link is 1Gb Ethernet.

For some reason, when I sent a "burst" of 10 packets as fast as possible from the FPGA, they arrive out of order to the x86. I use tcpdump in an isolated process to determine the ordering of the received packets.

Is it possible the Linux kernel is responsible for the shuffling of the packets, or does the Linux kernel respect the ordering as provided by the 1Gb interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of frames depends on the protocol and therefore is part of the TCP/IP transport layer. For example, [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) guarantees ordering while [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) does not. If you examine the [ethernet frame structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure) you'll see there are no provisions for ordering.